# Creating a pair list from a list in a functional way

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I have a list, for example `[0,12,16,23,66]` and I want to create another list that generates 
`["0-12","12-16","16-23","23-66"]`.

I could write it using a simple for loop but i want to find out the best way to do it using functional constructs. 
 I could hack my way by using a `reduce` or a `foldLeft` but that doesn't feel right as it would be pushing to a list outside the scope of the function. Is there a better way to do this?

I am using Java 8, but I am open to the idea behind doing it rather than how it's done in a language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such an operation can be done easily using the [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library. It provides a `pairMap` method that gives the ability to perform an operation on two consecutive items from a Stream:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(0,12,16,23,66);
    List<String> result = StreamEx.of(list).pairMap((i1, i2) -> i1 + "-" + i2).toList();
    System.out.println(result); // prints [0-12, 12-16, 16-23, 23-66]
}
```

If you don't want to use this library, you can still do it with the Stream API using an `IntStream` going through the indexes of the input list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(0,12,16,23,66);
    List<String> result = IntStream.range(0, list.size() - 1)
                                   .mapToObj(i -> list.get(i) + "-" + list.get(i+1))
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: The second solution is efficient specifically under the assumption that the list has sub-linear lookups. The first solution, as well as folding, works with linked lists, too.

Comment: ended up using StreamEx.pairMap . Exactly something that i was looking for.